# How to add two languages on a Website?

Tags: html, css

So I am creating a website and I need two scripts - Latin and Cyrillic. I know I can make two index.html files (indexlat.html and indexcyr.html) but I don't want to do that because I will have a lot of .html files, probaby more than 500. Is there any other (more efficient) way to make a website multilingual?

Will I have to use JS or JQuery?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What combination of technologies are you using to create your website?  Some of them have existing tools to deal with internationalization. Knowing what you are already using allows people answering this question to provide you an answer tailored to your needs rather than a general answer.

Answer (score 0):

1-First you must create an object which contains all static phrases for languages you want. something like this object

```
var phrases = {
    welcome: {
        en: "Welcome User",
        ar: "....",
        fa: "خوش آمدید"
    },
    ...
};
```

2-You must put an input for user to insert preferred language. A drop/down all an text input or something else and read its value in your `js` code. like

```
var globalLang = document.getElementBId("languageInput").value;
```

3-You must write a function `changeLang` when language changed, it triggeres. this function must change all static phrases in your page with true lang. something like below

```
function changeLang() {

    document.getElementById("welcomeDiv").innerHTML = phrases.welcome[globalLang];
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking you don't have to use JS. Consider this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    :lang(ne) {
        display: none;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p lang="en">English text</p>
    <p lang="ne">Translated text</p> <!--Will be hidden-->
</body>
</html>
```

How ever you still have to change css somehow. This can be done with JS/other server side code or probably carefully crafted relative URLs without no code.

Note: Think carefully do you want to put all your translations to html files itself just because you can. If there is great number of repeating phrases then maintaining translations can be painful.